# JOIN or subquery in SQL to grab data out of various tables needed

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, rdbms

I need to pull out some data from various tables using `PHP prepared statements` and `MySQL`.

**The items I need to plot the data into a graph are:**

`tblstudent`.`studentID`
`tblquestionnaire`.`questionnaireID`
`tblstudentAnswer`.`answer`

The database design looks like this with my table joins.
[image: DB Design]

I have attempted to use `INNER JOIN`'s, however I cannot join `tblquestionnaire` into it as I do not share a key with that table and the `student` table or with the `studentAnswer` table.

Any guidance would be much appreciated in how I get those pieces of information out within an SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking it.

to get all student Ids, with their answers and the questionaire ID.

The following query is enough.

```
SELECT
    sta.studenID
    ,qq.questionnaireID
    ,sta.answer
FROM 
  studentAnswer sta
INNER JOIN 
    questionnaireQuestions qq ON sta.questionnID =  qq.questionnID
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. I must have been over thinking, I thought you had to join all the tables together i.e. perform 2 inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need the `questionnaire` table to get `questionnaireID` - `questionnaireQuestions` contains it and it can be directly linked to `studentAnswer`. Second of all, you don't need the `students` table to get `studentID` because `studentAnswer` contains it. So you can simply follow this logic:

- you can get `questionnaireID` from `questionnaireQuestions`
- you can link `questionnaireQuestions` with `studentAnswer` through `questionID` to get `answer` and `studentID`

This bring us to a simple join of two tables:

```sql
SELECT sa.studentID, qq.questionnaireID, sa.answer
FROM studentAnswer sa
INNER JOIN questionnaireQuestions qq
ON qq.questionID = sa.questionID
```

The point is - always look for the shortest route to extract your data. Don't involve any extra tables if it can be avoided. This is where your diagram will come in handy. Looking at it, you can see that `questionnaireQuestions` is "closer" (one step less to connect) to `studentAnswer` than `questionnaire`. Since it contains the data you need, it's logical to use it over `questionnaire`.

Now let's say you needed `questionnaireName` along with `firstName` and `lastName` of the student. Even though you can't directly join `questionnaire` to `student`, you can do it through `questionnaireQuestions` and `studentAnswers`. Joins can contain tables you're not selecting from - it's a mechanism of connecting data. Then you'd follow this logic:

- you can get `questionnaireName` from `questionnaire`
- you can link `questionnaire` to `questionnaireQuestions` through `questionnaireID`
- you can link `questionnaireQuestions` to `studentAnswer` through `questionID`
- you can link `studentAnswer` to `student` through `studentID`

This brings us to a query like this:

```sql
SELECT q.questionnaireName, s.firstName, s.lastName
FROM questionnaire q
INNER JOIN questionnaireQuestions qq ON qq.questionnaireID = q.questionnaireID
INNER JOIN studentAnswer sa ON qq.questionID = sa.questionID
INNER JOIN student s ON s.studentID = sa.studentID
```